# Set position of listview based on input in EditText Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am making an dictionary application where i intend to have many words.(around 1 Lakh)
I am rendering it in a list along with the meaning of the Word.

I am using the custom array adapter to fill in the listView and inflating the custom layout in listview.

Here is my scenarion :

1> I have edittext which allows user to enter the words which they are looking for.
2> Once user type word , for example **R** , i want to set Selction of the list view, where first letter is R , And once user type next work , lets say **RE** , the list view position should be changed to the list position where first two letters are **RE** .

To implement this i have added addTextchanged Listner to the edittext and filtered the adapter but it is not working. Once i type something list getting empty.

Can you please suggest me better approach or how can i implement following functionality.

Any help would highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: check this link once http://androiddevelopersblogs.blogspot.in/2012/06/custom-list-view-list-view-with-images.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is two suggestion for you.
**1**, Use [`Search Interface`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) with `Content Provider`. This way is a little bit complex but more effective for manager large data. This `Dictionary sample` provides two searching option
 -  Type keyword and suggestion listview dropdown with match items. You just click and get meaning of word
 -  Type **not** complete keyword and press magnifier icon an it return relative match items listview.

You can download sample and import or just `Create a sample project` in `Eclipse` and choose `SearchableDictionary` example.

**2**, Stick to `Edittext` and filter `ListView`. Add your code so we can help you out.

In my opinion `AutoCompleteTextView` with a `ListView` below is not convenience for `User`. You had suggested dropdown listview (in `AutoCompleteTextView`), user expect to get word's meaning  when they click suggestion not click again in ListView below (two clicks to get word's meaning). An `AutoCompleteTextView` with `TextView` display word meaning seem suitable.

Comment: Hello, I have initially begin with starting implementation with Search Interface. But was lost some where in managing Data. I think i will rethink over it and try that approach because i would probably adding more support after some time.                                                         The Problem with the listview and editext is that the i am able to filter the adapter but i am not able to do it for custom adapter..... Anyway tahnkf for the help and suggestion...

Comment: @ YUL : I am adding support for TTS as well.. I have a question what will be the minimum OS support i would be able to give if i use SearchInterface and Text To Speach.

Comment: According to `Android Developer` `TTS` supports minimum API lvl4 mean Android1.6. Just paste your code to paste.org or pastebin and attack link in question. We'll try to help you out. When you have time, change to search interface

Answer (score 1):

If i am understanding your requirement correctly then you want to minimize the typing that a user has to do in your dictionary application by scrolling the list based on letters typed. 
You can achieve the same result with an auto complete text view in place of edit text.
As the user types some letters the android will display all the words starting with those words.
And when the user selects the correct word the list can be scrolled to that position.
Here is sample code for this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:completionThreshold="3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

public class AutoCompleteActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

```
private AutoCompleteTextView edit;

private static final String[] items={"lorem", "ipsum", "dolor",
    "sit", "amet", "consectetuer", "adipiscing", "elit", "morbi",
    "vel", "ligula", "vitae", "arcu", "aliquet", "mollis","etiam",
    "vel", "erat", "placerat", "ante", "porttitor", "sodales", 
    "pellentesque", "augue", "purus"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    edit=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.edit);
    edit.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
            items));

    edit.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long Id)
{
    Toast.makeText(AutoCompleteActivity.this, items[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // scroll the list to the correct position
    //listView.setSelection(position);
}
```

}

Here an adapter is attached with the autoCompleteText view and when the user types, it displays
 all the  words starting with those letters in a drop down list and when the user
clicks on any word in the list the onItemClick method is called.

I hope this will help

Comment: Hello, Autocomplete textview is not a solution as i am using custom adapter and i have to bind list..... Thanks for the suggestion and help.. I would use Search Interface.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SearchableDictionary extends Activity {

    private TextView mTextView;
    private ListView mListView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // handles a click on a search suggestion; launches activity to show word
        Intent wordIntent = new Intent(this, WordActivity.class);
        wordIntent.setData(intent.getData());
        startActivity(wordIntent);
        finish();
    } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // handles a search query
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        showResults(query);
    }
}

/**
 * Searches the dictionary and displays results for the given query.
 * @param query The search query
 */
private void showResults(String query) {

    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null,
                            new String[] {query}, null);

    if (cursor == null) {
        // There are no results
        mTextView.setText(getString(R.string.no_results, new Object[] {query}));
    } else {
        // Display the number of results
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        String countString = getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.search_results,
                                count, new Object[] {count, query});
        mTextView.setText(countString);

        // Specify the columns we want to display in the result
        String[] from = new String[] { DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
                                       DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION };

        // Specify the corresponding layout elements where we want the columns to go
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.word,
                               R.id.definition };

        // Create a simple cursor adapter for the definitions and apply them to the ListView
        SimpleCursorAdapter words = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                                      R.layout.result, cursor, from, to);
        mListView.setAdapter(words);

        // Define the on-click listener for the list items
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Build the Intent used to open WordActivity with a specific word Uri
                Intent wordIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WordActivity.class);
                Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                                                String.valueOf(id));
                wordIntent.setData(data);
                startActivity(wordIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.search:
            onSearchRequested();
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

}